# onActivityResult DialogFragment doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog

I'm having a problem by executing fileupload in android through fragmentDialog.Befire to test the button I made activity etc to test it, evrything works fine, but since i put it under dilogfragment nothing works:

```
public class UploadF extends DialogFragment{

    ....

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    gallery_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gal = new Intent();
            gal.setType("image/*");
            gal.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gal, "Select Picture"), SELECT_IMAGE);

        }

    });




    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult( requestCode,  resultCode,  data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
                ....

                if ( selectedImagePath != null ) {
                    UploadFileI task = new UploadFileI( getActivity());
                    task.execute( url );
                }
            }



        }

    }



}
```

Comment: I mean when I click nothing works, it doesn't send nothing, no reaction

Comment: when I click on uploadFile im my menu, nothing goes

Comment: All code you have shown seems to be valid. The parts that are required for us to help you are not there. E.g. how do you launch the DialogFragment? From what Activity, by calling what? Help us out!

Answer (score 6):

You are right, that nothing is happening. `Activity`'s have a method `onActivityResult`, and `Fragment`'s have one as well. This might be confusing, and in order to progress, try to use the Activity context by calling:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gal, "Select Picture"), SELECT_IMAGE);
```

This way, the Activity that created your UploadF will receive the result. So you have to move your `onActivityResult` to your `Activity`:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){}
    ...
}
```

Function outside of your UploadF and inside the parent Activity.
If this doesn't work, search for startActivityForResult inside DialogFragment

Comment: Hi, but, how to get the fragment from the activity since I have a lot of objects to handle on results? (i'm facing the same situation)

Comment: Inside the Activity, use getFragmentManager().findFragmentById() or getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()